# how to pass a list to a Data Frame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting this error `pyspark.sql.utils.Illegal Argument Exception: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.`

Old column names (6): `vin`, `age`, `var`, `rim`, `cap`, `cur`.

New column names (2): `vin`, `age` for the code below:

```py
schema = StructType([
StructField( 'vin', StringType(), True),StructField( 'age', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'var', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'rim', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cap', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cur', IntegerType(), True)
  ])

data = [['tom', 10,54,87,23,90], ['nick', 15,63,23,11,65], ['juli', 14,87,9,43,21]]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
use=['vin','age']

df1=df.toDF(*use)

df1.show()
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `df.select(*use)`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to cut that data frame to the list columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select certain columns from a dataframe using a list of column names, use `select`, not `toDF`:

```
use = ['vin','age']
df1 = df.select(*use)
```

`toDF` is only suitable for renaming all columns in a dataframe. It's not suitable for selecting certain columns.